# No overload for method 'GetTouchPoint' takes 0 arguments

Tags: c#, touch, pixelsense

I'm developing an application for the Sur40 with PixelSense2.0. I'm trying to capture the touch input but it keeps providing me the same error: `No overload for method 'GetTouchPoint' takes 0 arguments`.

This is my code so far:

```
    void SurfaceWindow1_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {


        this.TouchDown += new EventHandler<TouchEventArgs>(SurfaceWindow1_TouchDown);

    }

    void SurfaceWindow1_TouchDown(object sender, TouchEventArgs e)
    {
        LoadAnimationControl2 ani1 = new LoadAnimationControl2();
        ani1.Margin.Left = e.GetTouchPoint().Position.X;
        ani1.Margin.Bottom = e.GetTouchPoint().Position.Y;
        MainGrid.Children.Add(ani1);
    }
```

Does anybody have a suggestion how to deal with this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
void SurfaceWindow1_TouchDown(object sender, TouchEventArgs e)
{
    LoadAnimationControl2 ani1 = new LoadAnimationControl2();
    ani1.Margin.Left = e.GetTouchPoint(this).Position.X;
    ani1.Margin.Bottom = e.GetTouchPoint(this).Position.Y;
    MainGrid.Children.Add(ani1);
}
```

Comment: This code helped me a lot, but it crashes on ani1.Margin with the error: Cannot modify the return value of 'System.Windows.FrameworkElement.Margin' becaus it is not a variable. How can i Solve this?

Comment: @NielsVerhoeven I had a quick look at the docs and it appears that you just set it to a Thickness `btn1.Margin = new Thickness(60);` Reference here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.frameworkelement.margin.aspx

Answer (score 2):

GetTouchPoint() has a required input parameter.  There is no method signature that doesn't use a parameter.  You need to pass in an IInputElement as a parameter to the method.

[**GetTouchPoint() MSDN Reference page**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.input.toucheventargs.gettouchpoint.aspx)

Answer (score 2):

Well according to the [docs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.input.toucheventargs.gettouchpoint.aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=csharp#code-snippet-1):

```
public TouchPoint GetTouchPoint(
    IInputElement relativeTo
)
```

It takes an `IInputElement` which is:  `The element that defines the coordinate space.`
and it returns:  `The current position of the touch device relative to the specified element.`

So what you need to do is pass in your "screen" or whatever the correct terminology is to get what is being viewed.